# R console output only shows most recent command in "if" condition

Tags: r, printing, console, printf

If I run this code in RStudio:

```
sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d", 1+1)
sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)

if (1){
  sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d", 1+1)
  sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)
}
```

I get this output:

```
> sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d", 1+1)
[1] "1 + 1 is: 2"
> sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)
[1] "2 + 2 is:  4"
> 
> if (1){
+   sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d", 1+1)
+   sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)
+ }
[1] "2 + 2 is:  4"
```

My question is why doesn't the first print statement in the if(1) condition (i.e.,. the 1+1 line) print to the console as well?  It seems that whenever I have an "if" condition with multiple lines of outputs that I want to print or plot, only the last one shows up.  How can I fix it so that all code output in an "if" statement appears in the console in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in more detail on https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-February/268969.html.

Essentially `sprintf()` doesn't actually print anything to the terminal it just calls a function that returns a string in r. (Usually R prints returned objects when not assigned to the terminal hence the usual behaviour). Inside a control block such as this if statement or a function call this behaviour is different. In these blocks only one object is printed by R which is the returned object. In an if statement this is the last object.

To get the behaviour you desire the `sprintf()` could be wrapped in a `cat()` or `print()` statement.

An alternative approach to this would be to use the `print()` and `paste()` functions in combination.

All these behaviours have been summarised in a reprex below.

```r
sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d \n", 1+1)
#> [1] "1 + 1 is: 2 \n"
sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)
#> [1] "2 + 2 is:  4"


if (1){
    sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d \n", 1+1)
    sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2)
}
#> [1] "2 + 2 is:  4"

if (1){
  cat(sprintf("1 + 1 is: %d \n", 1+1))
  print(sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 2+2))
  sprintf("2 + 2 is:  %d", 3+3)
}
#> 1 + 1 is: 2 
#> [1] "2 + 2 is:  4"
#> [1] "2 + 2 is:  6"


if(1) {
  print(paste("1 + 1 is:", 1 + 1))
  print(paste("2 + 2 is:", 2 + 2))
}
#> [1] "1 + 1 is: 2"
#> [1] "2 + 2 is: 4"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>